# Phone won't automatically reconnect to the mobile internet

Tags: usb-debugging, connection-issues, mobile-network, 4g

My phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 10, Android 11) spontaneously disconnects from the mobile internet after being connected for a couple of hours, and it **won't** automatically reconnect. Can stay unconnected for however long. After I switch to the flight mode and back, it reconnects for some time, then loses connection again.

Is there any way to **diagnose** what is the problem? Maybe to find some **logs** from the network hardware.

I thought this might be due to a defective SIM card because the same problem happened to the phone it was previously installed in, but I had SIM card reissued at a mobile operator's office. The same problem is there with the new SIM card. What's the chance it's defective again? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**UPD 2:**

Turned out that 4g connection always disappeared during a call, and not just spontaneously as I originally thought.

**UPD 1:**

A little clarification: when internet is Ok the signal level has a 4g label, then in an hour or so the 4g label spontaneously disappears, and so does the internet connection. But the phone does calls and receives them.

Thanks to Robert I managed to get logs by

```
adb logcat -P "" # and then after waiting for the internet to vanish
adb logcat -b radio
```

A lot of messages say 2224 at the presumable time of failure such as
`[0]onDataSetupComplete: error apn=internet.tele2.ru, cause=2224, requestType=NORMAL`

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/DataFailCause?hl=ru) describes it as "SIM was marked by the network as invalid for the circuit and/or packet service domain." *How could this happen* after sim worked fine for the previous 40 mins? *Is there anything I can do to prevent it?*

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-2TnQYbhzLucBQ_fhipbrUKNOOoiMr74?usp=sharing) are the logs, but after seeing what a mess they are, I wouldn't expect anyone to look through them. But if you actually do, the logs start with turning the airplane mode on and off, then a lot of messages start at 22:31 (where the loss is probably is) then by 23:01 there is definitely no internet connection.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Some times there are incompatibilities between phone and mobile network provider. Which provider do you use and in which country?

Comment: @Robert , the country is Russia, the provider is Tele2. I don't think incompatibility with the provider is the case, because it's a popular provider, it has proved to work fine with analogous phone model (Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro) and a few others.

Comment: Android has a `radio` log buffer for "radio/telephony related messages". You can get the current messages when connected via USB with activated adb by executing `adb logcat radio` on the PC (Android SDK or minimal ADB required on PC + adb drivers).

Comment: Thank you, @Robert ! This is quite an abundant log buffer :) I'll try to collect the data and see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the mobile provider side. It took some effort to convince them them to consider this option, but after that they fixed it in few days. But no complaints in the end. The problem probably arised because the number was registered ~15 years ago.